# Image not converting to base 64 in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert the HTML web pages to PDF I am using Xhtml2pdf library for this, this does not display images on the PDF therefore, its needed to convert the images in base 64 which can be displayed on the PDF, I have wrote the base 64 and applying the my custom filter on the image and its not converting it in the base 64 because image is not visible in the generated PDF. What am I doing wrong following is my code:

view.py

```
class Instagram_Report_View(TemplateView):

    template_name = "Target_Management_System/InstagramPerson_Target_Report.html"
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            object_gtr_id = kwargs['object_gtr_id']
            profile = acq.get_data_response_object_by_gtr_id(ObjectId(object_gtr_id))
            print(profile.to_mongo())
            #return render(request, 'Reports_Management_Unit/pdf_file.html',{'profile':profile})
            pdf=render_to_pdf('Reports_Management_Unit/pdf_file.html')
            return pdf
```

custom_filter.py (in this file the code for image to base 64 is written)

```
from django import template
import base64
from io import StringIO
import urllib.request
import requests
register=template.Library()

@register.filter
def convert_to_base64(url):
    
    
    return base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)
```

pdf_file.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load custom_filter %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    

</head>

<body>
<img src="{% static 'Reports_Management_Unit/img/profile_pic.jpg' | convert_to_base64 %}">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making use of an existing service? Would that be an option for you?

[How to generate a PDF from an HTML / CSS (including images) source in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786463/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-an-html-css-including-images-source-in-python)

has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/786499/3907258) that may be helpful